# Error by Mock in Unit test asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I am doing a unit test project to test a read method in a controller. I am trying to mock the Repository but I am getting a problem.

There is an App Repository which contains all the Repositories. and another Repository for users:

```
var repositoriesMock = new Mock<IAppRepositories>();
var userMock = new Mock<UserRepository> ();
repositoriesMock.SetupGet(x => x.Users).Returns(
                    partnerMock.Object
                );

userMock.SetupGet(x => x.GetUserDto(false, 1) ).Returns(
                    new List<GeschaeftspartnerDto> {user1, user2}.AsQueryable()
                );
```

in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var list = this.AppRepositories.Users.GetUserDto(false, 1).ToList();

}
```

but I am receiving an Error in uerMock.SetupGet

> Expression is not a property access: x => x.GetUserDto(False, 1)

what is going on? why am I getting this error?

Comment: Show the definition for `GetUserDto` and its declaring type `UserRepository`. Does UserRepository have a backing interface?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: You have not provided enough details about the object in order to be able to help you properly. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Mock.Setup instead of Mock.SetupGet.

Comment: now I am receiving a different error:Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.GetUserDto(False, 1)

Comment: You need to mark your UserRepository.GetUserDto as virtual or else mock an interface of the user repository instead of the concrete class.

Comment: how should I do that?